# win 10 Pro: How to avoid change of screen resolution?

Tags: windows-10, resolution, group-policy

I know that in Windows 7 there was a Group Policy that could be used to disallow changes of screen resolution.

I'm googling but I cannot find the policy name/path.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type gpedit.msc in the Open box and click OK.

In the Group Policy Editor, navigate to:

> User Configuration/Administrative Templates/Control Panel/Display

In the right side window, double click the Disable the Display control panel item.

Here is a screenshot from Windows 10 Pro
[image: GPO for display control]